# como arreglo mi problema con el webdriver de selenium

Tags: python, windows10, selenium-webdriver

estoy intentando usar el webdriver de selenium en windows, pero tras poner

```
driver: object = webdriver.Chrome(executeable_path='C:\\Users\\el camino a\\chromedriver.exe')
```

obtengo el error

```
camino a python.exe: can't open file '/Python Console': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

python.exe si esta en ese directorio, y estoy trabajando en windows 10

Comment: Hola Jose, no se con seguridad si puede ser tu caso, pero te aconsejo usar siempre `/` para las cadenas que especifican las rutas. Escapar  "\" (doble barra invertida, "\\") como haces o usar cadenas crudas `r"ruta\a\..."` dan problemas en ciertos casos, `/` en cambio funciona en cualquier SO. ¿La ruta al driver tiene espacios u otras "particularidades"?

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo algunos consejos como los que te ha puesto @FJSevilla y otros más

- Usar siempre la barra y no la contrabarra, es decir, usar **"/"**
- Que no haya espacios en blanco hacia tu directorio o carácteres raros. Los espacios es común sustituirlos por la barra baja **_**
- Por otro lado salvo que lo hayas cambiado, cuando te descargas **chromedriver** y descomprimes, viene dentro de una carpeta llamada "chromedriver". Por lo que la parte final de la ruta sería `../chromedriver/chromedriver.exe`
- En ocasiones Selenium saca este error, por tener una versión desactualizada de chromedriver que no es soportada.